# Android two-way data binding working one way only

Tags: android, android-databinding, androidx, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm having this problem for a while, hope someone can help me

I'm trying to implement two-way data binding for the first time, but I'm facing a weird problem.

The problem here is that every time that I set a value of a live data from my view model, the UI changes, but when I change the edit text value on the UI, it does not reflect on the view model live data value.
Seems like the *two-way* data binding is working *one-way* only, when the value is set from the view model

I have my view model, something like this:

```
class CreateAssignmentViewModel(): ViewModel() {
    val assignment = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

then my activity:

```
class CreateAssignmentActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private val createViewModel: CreateAssignmentViewModel by viewModel()
    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityCreateAssignmentBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_create_assignment)
        viewBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
        viewBinding.createViewModel = createViewModel
    }
}
```

and then on my activity xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="createViewModel"
            type="com.marcelo.tasks.assignments.create.CreateAssignmentViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".assignments.create.CreateAssignmentActivity">

        <EditText
            style="@style/Base.EditText"
            android:text="@{createViewModel.assignment}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

[image: image showing that its not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you didn't set two way data binding in your view. You have to use `@={}` for two way data binding. Check below:

Use

```
<EditText
    android:text="@={createViewModel.assignment}" />
```

Instead of

```
<EditText
    android:text="@{createViewModel.assignment}" />
```